# Mark newly added row in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a situation that user go to page with Kendo Grid and he can add new item to this Grid. Before he refresh page - new items are visible at the top of the Grid (stantard Kendo UI way)

I want to mark newly added rows, for example I want to have them shown in different colour than the "old' ones. 
Is is possible to do this?

Comment: Is it inline editing grid ? Please post your Grid

Comment: you should use a row template
are you using mvc wrapper or the JS version of Kendo UI ?